# JavaScript, how in most effective way get second value from string like "var1-var2"

Tags: javascript

I know about .split( "-" ,2), but how can i make something like this

```
var str = "123-341235";
alert( str.split( "-",2 ) . [2] )<--- to get second one (341235) value?
```

Tnx for help All!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two simple solutions, which have roughly the same performance:

```
var str = "123-341235";
str.split('-')[1]; // => "341235" (slower)
str.slice(str.indexOf('-')+1); // => "341235" (faster)
```

This [jsPerf benchmark](http://jsperf.com/split-vs-slice-indexof) shows the "slice/indexOf" solution to be about twice as fast on Chrome and Firefox.

Note that for either solution you'll have to check that the hypen character really exists before retrieving the second part of the string; I would bet that adding the check still leaves the "slice/indexOf" solution to be much faster.

Answer (score 5):

You just have to omit the "." (dot) and start your array index with 0:

```
str.split("-", 2)[1];
```

Comment: Alternative: `str.split("-", 2).pop()`

Comment: yes, but this is not very effective: http://jsperf.com/split-vs-slice-indexof/4 :)

Answer (score 2):

I usually use this:

```
str.split("-", 2).pop()
```

Answer (score 1):

In one line:

```
alert('123-341235'.split('-',2 )[1]);
```

In two you could've guessed:

```
var str = "123-341235";
alert( str.split('-',2)[1]) );
```

Arrays are *zero based*, meaning that the first element of an array has index 0, the second index 1 and so on. Furthermore, a dot between the array and index value (`[i]`) generates an error.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
alert( str.split( "-",2 )[0] + '/' + str.split( "-",2 )[1]);
```

Comment: $.log( $(value) . attr( "uid" ) . split( "-",2,1 )  [1] );
mostly same. Thank your!

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "123-341235";
alert( (str.split("-"))[1] );
```

- remeber that arrays are zero based, so the second number is index 1...

Answer (score 1):

The fastest, IMHO

```
var str = "123-341235";
alert(str.substr(str.indexOf("-")+1));
```

Comment: but now the fastest to write every time :)

Answer (score 0):

the second argument tells split how many splits to perform.  See

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

do

```
var tokens = str.split("-");
tokens[0] // 123
tokens[1] // 341235
```

split returns an array of the results, and remember arrays are 0-based, so [0] is the first results and [1] is the second result.

Answer (score 0):

A JavaScript question on SO is never complete without some **regular expression overkill** :

```
var tokens = /^\d+-(\d+)$/.exec(str);

if (tokens) {
    console.log(tokens[1]);
}
```

In hindsight, this allows for format validation.

Comment: Who say that thisd will be digiat always :) better is [^\-]+?\-.* in fact. 
Also it can be in one line: tokens=/.../?tokens[1]:false; , as i understood ;)